# How to close a pop up window using the anchor's OnClick in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php page that opens a pop window. it contains the search results. each result is inside the anchor tags.

I can open a new tab containing the information in the parent window, but somehow the `OnClick` function does not work. what i want to do is when the user select a link, will open a new tab then the pop up window automatically close. I dont know why the `OnClick` event is not doing what I want.

```
<?php
<a href='edit.php?id=$id' target='_blank' onClick='self.close();'>Listq</a>
?>
```

the code above works but it closes the pop up before opening the **new tab**. please help. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to close the popup **from the new tab** on load and **not from the popup**:

```
window.opener.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`onClick='setTimeout("self.close();",1)'`

Comment: hi @Tim Stamp, it did not work. I even added javascript:  before the function.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this

```
<a href="#" onclick="closeWin()">Close</a>

    function closeWin()
{
self.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `onmouseup` in stead of `onclick`. And if that fails too you can also do the opening of the popup in the onclick with `window.open()`. That way your order is maintained.

So it would look like:

```
<a href='#' onClick="window.open('edit.php?id=$id'); self.close(); return false;">Listq</a>
```

And get writ of the `<?php` and `?>` tag, or put the anchor in an echo if this is PHP.

Comment: @hi nl-x: I tried this,too, but it did not work. but thanks for answering, appreciate it.